# Жанровое определение "смешного" прозаического произведения

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика

Как определить жанр прозаических произведений крупной формы, как-то роман, или средней формы, как-то повесть, содержащих много комических сцен, проникнутых добрым юмором, побуждающих иной раз трепетать от смеха? Речь идёт о таких произведениях, в которых комическая составляющая является ведущей или одной из ведущих образных сфер.

Например: "Вечера на хуторе близ Диканьки" Гоголя, "Двенадцать стульев" Ильфа и Петрова.

Комический роман (повесть), юмористический роман (повесть)?

Answer (score 2):

> Комический роман (повесть), юмористический роман (повесть)?

Да. Сейчас "юмористический" употребляется чаще, я думаю. Ещё могут быть различные (под)варианты *сатирический*, *сатирико-юмористический*, *трагикомический* и т.п.